# ListView with CursorAdapter - header scroll not working

Tags: android, android-listview, android-cursoradapter

I got an oven-common ListView + CursorAdapter + Items with SectionHeaders activity. And I'm stuck with an usability issue.

When I do a fling gesture starting from a non-header item, the list scrolls OK. But when the fling starts from a section header it doesn't scroll.

The adapter has the following code:

```
@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    return getItemViewType(position) != HEADER;
}
```

If I change it to always return true, it becomes possible to fling from the section headers, but they become clickable.

How can I enable fling/scrolling on the section headers and keep it disabled for clicking?

Comment: do you use `addHeaderView()` to create header?

Comment: No, I that's not the case. I'm editing the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

There was a very weird method override on the custom `ListView`. The `onInterceptTouchEvent` was overridden without calling the super method:

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    return true;
}
```

Should be (at least):

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

But I just dropped it. It fixed that bug, and some other odd behaviors (that we were turning a blind eye to).